# Light and Free Asp.NET Developing Tools

Tags: asp.net

I am looking for a tool which can edit asp.net pages and supports intellisense. I know several tools like Web Developer Express but I am looking more lightly softwares and of course it must be free because I am not that rich to pay money to a software :) and if it was open source,it'd be more great (:

If you knew any and shared it with me,it'd be great.

Thanks in advance.

1. Free
2. Light
3. Supports Intellisense, Syntax Highlighting and Code Formatting
4. For Asp.NET
5. (Optional) Open Source

These are the requirement that I want the software to does have :)

Sorry for wanting so much things.. :)

Comment: What is wrong with the Visual Web Developer Express?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that, but some people says it's too complex to edit pages and so on,so they want me to find simple yet useful editor.
Thanks.

Actually, I am using webdev and I like it tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MonoDevelop is a IDE for C#/.Net on Linux, but it sounds like it might suit your needs.

Here's the link:  http://monodevelop.com/

Comment: Thanks but I think it's for heavily development environment. Actually What I want is light developer tools like notepad but it should support intellisense and syntax highlight and formatting.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could try notepad++ and set it to c#/vb. You won't get auto complete but you will have a light text editor with syntax highlighting. I could be wrong, but I believe the only free tools with everything you want are the VS Express IDEs that MS offers.

Comment: Actually, It looks so :(

Answer (score 1):

Here is another list from archive.org:

http://web.archive.org/web/20071217202115/http://www.dotnetcoders.com/web/Articles/ShowArticle.aspx?article=49

Comment: I've checked them out.
1. Not all of them for c#
2. most of them are not free
3. and web matrix is for framework 1.1 and 1.0 and it's being continued developing any more for new frameworks.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have some very particular requirements. They are not unreasonable but I'm not sure you will find all of those things and FREE.  If you have the skills and/or desire,  maybe you should consider building the tool you want for yourself.

Comment: Well,I on't think I can't build a new one :)

Answer (score 1):

Intellisense, syntax highlighting, and code formatting, particularly in multi-context files like those used in ASP.NET, are **precisely why** the available editors aren't terribly lightweight.

If you can give up *perfect* syntax highlighting and *complete* Intellisense, I recommend using a general-purpose programmer's editor such as UltraEdit, which is inexpensive and very fast. UE doesn't force you to bundle your source code into "solutions," has powerful search and replace, etc.

But on the flip side, for that extra speed, the highlighting and other fancy features are implemented using pattern recognition, not true behind-the-scenes compilation or interpretation of your code. So it can highlight certain words, recognize comment blocks, etc., but it doesn't have the ability to follow along and provide object-specific Intellisense, etc.

Comment: Actually,Instead of UltraEdit I'd prefer Notepad++.